# Closed subgroup and closed orbit

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a topological group and $\Gamma$ be a lattice in $G$. Consider the action of $G$ on the homogeneous space $G/\Gamma$ by left translation.

Let $F$ be a closed subgroup of $G$ and $x\in G/\Gamma$. Is it always true that $Fx$ is also closed in $G/\Gamma$?

If necessary,one can assume $G$ is a Lie group (I am not sure if this is relevant though)

Comment: I mean, say, $G=\Bbb{R}, \Gamma=\Bbb{Z}, F=\langle a\rangle$ where $a$ is irrational.

Comment: ... in this case the quotient space is a circle and some orbits are not closed.

Comment: Good point thanks! @JCAA

Comment: I post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $ G=\Bbb{R}, \Gamma=\Bbb{Z}, F=\langle a\rangle$ where $a$ is irrational. Then the quotient space is a circle and the orbits are not closed.